# Update of navigation property in EF7 does not get saved

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have simple model:

```
public class Post
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { set; get; }
        //non-important properties stripped, to focus on problem
        public virtual Resource Resource { set; get; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { set; get; }
}
public class Resource
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { set; get; }

        [Url]
        public string Url { set; get; }
}
```

and DbContext (I use ASP.NET identity in this project, if this is relevant):

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            var postEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Post>();
            postEntity.Reference(p => p.Resource).InverseCollection(); //no navigation property on Resource side
            postEntity.Collection(p => p.Tags).InverseReference(tag => tag.Post);
            postEntity.ToTable("Posts");

            var resourceEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>();
            resourceEntity.ToTable("Resources");

            var tagEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>();
            tagEntity.Reference(t => t.Post).InverseCollection(p => p.Tags).Required(false);
            tagEntity.ToTable("Tags");
       }
}
```

After migration (SQL Server), database tables looks like expected - Post table has Foreign Key to ResourceId.

Creating Post's works fine, when I attach post.Resource (already created Resource).

**My problem occurs when I want to replace post.Resource**.
**By replace, I mean selecting one of already existing Resources and assigning it to post.**

`var resource2 = Database.Resources.First(r=>r.Url == "xyz");`

I have tried:

1. `post.Resource = resource2; Database.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;`
2. `Database.Entry(post).Property(p => p.Resource).CurrentValue = resource2;`
3. `post.Resource = null;`

**With different combinations of them also**, but none of them works. After calling `await SaveChangesAsync();` and looking up in database - there are no changes. How to perform the replace (update of foreign key) properly?

//Update 14.09.2015
*Issue was caused by additional select, performed to update One-To-Many relationship.* Full code:

```
        var Database new DbContext();
        var resource2 = Database.Resources.First(r=>r.Url == "xyz");
        var oldAssignedTags = Database.Posts.Include(p=>p.Tags).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == post.Id).Tags;
        var tags = newTags as List<Tag> ?? newTags.ToList();
        //TagComparer is irrelevant here
        var toRemove = oldAssignedTags.Except(tags, TagComparer);
        var toAdd = tags.Except(oldAssignedTags, TagComparer);

        foreach (var tag in toRemove)
        {
            Database.Entry(tag).State = EntityState.Deleted; //Database.Tags.Remove(tag);
        }

        foreach (var tag in toAdd)
        {
            tag.Post = post;
            post.Tags.Add(tag);
        }

        post.Resource = resource2;
        await Database.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: How are you creating the Post, and how are you populating `post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this may have something to do with *Eager Loading*, however I can't reproduce your issue with or without `AspNet.Identity`.  Running the below code results in the Resource always being updated.  Using `EntityFramework 7.0.0-beta7`.

**Code**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Init();
    WithEagerLoading();
    CleanUp();

    Init();
    WithoutEagerLoading();
    CleanUp();
}

private static void WithoutEagerLoading()
{
    var db = new MyContext();
    var post = db.Posts.First(); // no eager loading of child
    post.Resource = db.Resources.First(p => p.Url == "http://trend.atqu.in");
    db.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine($"2nd Resource.Id: {new MyContext().Posts.Include(p => p.Resource).First().Resource.Id}");
}

private static void WithEagerLoading()
{
    var db = new MyContext();
    var post = db.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Resource) // eager loading
        .First();
    post.Resource = db.Resources.First(p => p.Url == "http://trend.atqu.in");
    db.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine($"2nd Resource.Id: {new MyContext().Posts.Include(p => p.Resource).First().Resource.Id}");
}

private static void CleanUp()
{
    var db = new MyContext();
    db.Posts.RemoveRange(db.Posts);
    db.Resources.RemoveRange(db.Resources);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

private static void Init()
{
    var db = new MyContext();
    var resource = new Resource { Url = "http://atqu.in" };
    var resource2 = new Resource { Url = "http://trend.atqu.in" };
    var post = new Post { Resource = resource };
    db.Add(post);
    db.Add(resource);
    db.Add(resource2);
    db.SaveChanges();

    db = new MyContext();
    post = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Resource).First();
    resource = db.Resources.First(p => p.Url == "http://trend.atqu.in");
    Console.WriteLine($"1st Resource.Id: {post.Resource.Id}");
}
```

**Result**

```
1st Resource.Id: 0f4d222b-4184-4a4e-01d1-08d2bc9cea9b
2nd Resource.Id: 00ccae9c-f0da-43e6-01d2-08d2bc9cea9b
1st Resource.Id: 749f08f0-2426-4043-01d3-08d2bc9cea9b
2nd Resource.Id: 2e83b512-e8bd-4583-01d4-08d2bc9cea9b
```

**Edit 16/9**

The problem in the edited question's code is because you are instantiating `Database` after you have retrieved `post`.  `post` is not attached to that instance of `Database`, so when you attach the `Resource` to it and call `SaveChangesAsync` it does nothing, because `post` at that time has noting to do with the `Database` you are saving against.  That is why your workaround of selecting `post` post again (after the instantiation) causes it to be fixed - because then the instance of `post` is attached.  If you don't want to select `post` again, you should use the same `DbContext` instance to do the work above that you used to originally retrieve `post`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly my case. When you're replacing Resource, you are always creating new instance. In my case - I have a few existing Resources (with Id and Url set) - and then I want to replace post.Resource with one of existing Resources. It looks like post.Resource = Context.Resources.First(r=>r.Url == "xyz"). I obviously assert that the resource that I try to assing exists in database.

Comment: @MarcinZablocki I've updated the answer to attach an existing `Resource` and found the results are still the same - unable to reproduce.  I suggest you post all your code.

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated my question and pointed out the issue. I've workarounded it by saving database, then selecting post one more time, and then assingning resource & saving again.

Comment: @Marcin the code you posted, does it reflect the problem, or solve the problem?

Comment: I will check it out during next week, I think your answer deals with the problem ;)

Comment: Thanks for your time and great answer!